# Old School background html attribute

Tags: html

Think back into the days of old. Because apparently Google can't, so I can't verify I have it right. The background attribute for html `<body background="">` can you do `background="none"` or `transparent` or `0`? Without CSS (it has to be WITHOUT CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `HTML 4.01` [DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) (*as an example*, presuming `HTML5` is what is compared against), here is a sample on the usage of `background` attribute in `body` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>DOCTYPE 4.01</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#DDDDDD" background="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg/220px-Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg">
  Hello World!
</body>

</html>
```

We can use [`background`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-background) with `HTML 4.01` DTD. The same applies with [`bgColor`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor).

For `background`, the **value of this attribute is a URI** that designates an image resource. The image generally *tiles the background* as can be visualized in the above snippet.

---

Sample snippet in `HTML 4.01` with `bgColor` and `background="none"` (where `background` is not taken into consideration):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>DOCTYPE 4.01</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#D5D5D5" background="none">
  Hello World!
</body>

</html>
```

---

Quote from [**W3C**](https://www.w3.org/)

> [**background = uri**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-background)
>
> The value of this attribute is a URI that designates an image
>   resource. The image generally tiles the background (for visual
>   browsers).
>
> [**bgcolor = color**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor)
>
> This attribute sets the background color for the document body or
>   table cells.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. If you can't add an external CSS file, just try inline CSS on that element?

`style="background: none;"`

Comment: The code that I am using, ignores CSS.  Completely ignores it.  Old school HTML it responds to.

Comment: @BlowFish what about leaving the quotes empty? background=""

Answer (score 0):

I remember in that days i did 1x1px png image with black dot inside, and optacy of 25%, then put it in the background, as pattren

but propably there is a way by pure html as well

Answer (score 0):

The attribute you are looking for is `bgcolor`. This will take hex, color name or rgb() value. AFAIK there is no way to get it transparent. It seems that you might be willing to take this path: use an iframe with `allowtransparency`.

Side note: `background` refers to an URL.

Answer (score 0):

[The value for background is a URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-background) and `none` or any of the other values you mention are not URIs so, no, you cannot do that. The best you could do is leave it blank.

> The value of this attribute is a URI that designates an image
>   resource.

Of course I'm assuming you mean HTML4.01 since [the `background` attribute on the body does not exist in HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features).